# How to pass List<SelectOption> in the invocablemethod

Tags: invocable-method

```
  public static List<SelectOption> mimicUserProfile(List<List<Id>> IDs){


  }
```

Comment: Please do not just post a piece of code in the question body, provide some explanation why you need to pass the List of data - [ask]

Comment: To add to what @DaveHumm said,  If you post what you've written so far and where you're stuck, I'm confident you'll find plenty of people willing to assist you. SFSE is a Q&A forum where we look to help each other by asking and answering questions about real problems or errors with our code. Posting requests to write code for you generally get closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to say return ?

If you go through the documentation here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm

I guess SelectOptions is not one of the supported Datatypes.

[image]

Comment: i want to return id and name from the invicablemethod is there any work around

Comment: Just check the last point, you can return user defined type, so you can essentially return a List of Wrapper class.